# How to return custom 404 response when id not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I always wonder what is the best error response code in folowing situation:

```
public IActionResult Index(Guid id)
{
    var entity = _dbContext.Entities.Find(id);
 
    if (entity == null)
    {
         return NotFound(); //??
    }
    return View(entity)
}
```

404 - Not Found seems most appropriate, however, from debugging point of view, non-existing ID and wrong controller/action names are very different errors.

Anyway, I've decided to return custom error page with more explanatory message, so I can differentiate between 404 and 404.

**How to return custom 404 page from Controller's Action and default 404 in other cases?**

I would like to avoid returning HttpResponseMessage, since I would need to change return type of the Action.

*PS: In comments you may vote for 404 resp other response code you would use in this particular case.*

Comment: Have you tried return RedirectToAction("FourZeroFourpage"); ?

Comment: Redirect to Action returns 302 which is not what I want

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624995/asp-net-core-return-custom-response-when-method-is-not-allowed

Comment: You already use the best approach. `if (entity == null)
    {
         return NotFound(); //??
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305250/should-i-use-http-status-codes-to-describe-application-level-events) first.

Theoreticaly you shouldn't use HttpStatus-codes as Application Error Codes.

However, on a public website, 404 has one specific meaning:

> The requested resource could not be found but may be available in the
>   future. Subsequent requests by the client are permissible.

Calling `/getresource/347d2f3a-bd0f-4d0b-8c05-2e7f3f8f265e` is a resource. If this is not available you should use 404. If it is available, then 200. That's perfectly fine.

Google even says, you should send 404. From the [google support](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/181708?hl=en):

> Returning a code other than 404 or 410 for a non-existent page (or
>   redirecting users to another page, such as the homepage, instead of
>   returning a 404) can be problematic. Firstly, it tells search engines
>   that there’s a real page at that URL. As a result, that URL may be
>   crawled and its content indexed. Because of the time Googlebot spends
>   on non-existent pages, your unique URLs may not be discovered as
>   quickly or visited as frequently and your site’s crawl coverage may be
>   impacted (also, you probably don’t want your site to rank well for the
>   search query

For the implementation, I would just throw a custom `NotFoundException` (If you want to setup more meaningfull information) with all the data you need, and handle it globaly through the [`ExceptionFilterAttribute`](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/5df6e275-1148-45a1-a8b3-0ba2c7c9cea1.aspx). There you can turn it into a 404 response.

Of course you can let the original exception just bubble up to the `ExceptionFilterAttribute`, but then you have not that many possibilites for making it meaningfull.

Comment: Point taken, by why would I throw exception and then use exception filter to turn in into 404 response instead of directly returning NotFound, resp something like `IActionResult response = View("_CustomError"); response.responseCode = 404; return response`?

Comment: Bacause you written *I would like to avoid returning HttpResponseMessage, since I would need to change return type of the Action.*. Also because you don't need to be in a ControllerContext/ have a HttpContext to do so (For example you can use it in your service layer).

Comment: There has been some discussion in the asp.net team regarding HttpExceptions and they consider it antipattern, that's why they avoided it in mvc core

Comment: The reasoning is quite good: Its controller's responsibility to determine http response. Doing so from another layer is violation of SRP. Although in many cases it is just practical.

Comment: Why is throwing a `NotFoundException` violation of SRP, when this layer was told to access an item, which can not be found?

Comment: When you say NotFoundException, it sounds ok, but it is an HttpException. I dont think that some other layer than Controller or middleware should be aware of http.

Comment: The ExceptionFilterAttribute can filter other Exceptions than HttpExceptions ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [CreateResponse extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969056(v=vs.118).aspx) and would do something as follows:

`return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "foobar");`

I've used the `HttpStatusCode.NoContent` for something like this before. It really depends on what your business logic is and how you want to handle these cases. `NoContent` will result in a successful http call where as `NotFound` will be an error. `NotFound` will trigger your default MVC error page route(if you have that setup) and `NoContent` won't. Is this a response that is possible through normal use/traversing of the app or is it only something that will occur if a malicious user is tampering with urls? All of those pieces are what I take into consideration determining which http status code I want to return. Hope this helps!

Comment: 'Request.CreateResponse' does not exist in asp.net core. I would like to avoid returning HttpResponseMessage, since I would need to change return type of the Action.